# Sharepoint / Email related

Tags: email

I have the following SharePoint coding, which goes to an email

```
mailto:email1;email2;email3;?subject=Jobname%3B%20Problem%20with%20file%20%3Cfile-name%3E
```

I want to add the current day's date and time as continuation to the above coding in the subject line. Can somebody help me for that. BTW, i am novice to SharePoint and am a Mainframer !!

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure where you're calling the above from (Designer, Visual Studio or through the front-end), I can't be too specific, but SharePoint handles a lot of the string rendering to encode it as needed.

At any rate, a sure-fire way to do it without using the built in functions: Just as your mailto line has %20 to indicate a space, you should use [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) to render the symbols involved in a date/timestamp. Replace the colons, slashes and parentheses involved in whatever your desired format is.

Answer (score 0):

Inside sharepoint there's a shortcut to write today's date and time which is [Today].

Or another way to do this, is by Adding a Lookup variable, and setting it in Workflow Context (I think) and selecting When this worfklow starts, and it will set those variables you want.

Hope this helps.